# Flask: asynchronous response to client

Tags: python, asynchronous, background, flask, response

I'm using Flask to develop a web server in a python app. I'm achieving this scenario: the client (it won't be a browser) sends a request, the server does some long task in background and on completion sends the response back to the client **asynchronously**. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: There's a contradiction in your question: a (HTTP) response that is sent **on completion** of the task is not, by definition, asynchronous. You probably want to use two requests/responses, one for initiating the task, and another for getting the data. AFAIK, there's no way to do this using pure HTTP, although you could use a publish/subscribe pattern using PubSubHubbub, or, as @GamesBrainiac suggested, websockets

Comment: I think the best way to do this would be using web sockets.

Comment: But the client is not a browser... I think the best way to do this is *not* doing it in this way...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you ask cannot be done with the HTTP protocol. Each request receives a response synchronously. The closest thing to achieve what you want would be this:

The client sends the request and the server responds with a job id immediately, while it also starts a background task for this long calculation.

The client can then poll the server for status by sending the job id in a new request. The response is again immediate and contains a job status, such as "in progress", "completed", "failed", etc. The server can also return a progress percentage, which the client can use to render a progress bar.

You could also implement web sockets, but that will require socket enabled server and client.